# Подключение Siebar-a в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру кодинга.

добавил к первому сайдбару, что был в скине, код второго (my-sidebar):

```
function themonic_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'iconic-one' ),
        'id' => 'themonic-sidebar',
        'description' => __( 'This is a Sitewide sidebar which appears on posts and pages', 'iconic-one' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<p class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</p>',
    ) );



    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'My Sidebar', 'iconic-one' ),
        'id' => 'my-sidebar',
        'description' => __( 'This is a Sitewide sidebar which appears on posts and pages3', 'iconic-one2' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<p class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</p>',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'themonic_widgets_init' );
```

Скопировал файл sidebar.php и назвал его sidebar-second.php, в нём внёс следующие изменения:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'my-sidebar' ) ) : ?>

            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'my-sidebar' ); ?>
некий контент
    <?php else : ?>  
            некий контент
    <?php endif; ?>
```

А в файле header.php вписал такую конструкцию:

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
        <?php $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebar", true); // левый сайдбар
        get_sidebar($sidebar);?>
        <?php else : ?>
    <?php get_sidebar('second'); ?>
        <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
```

Я не программист, и не могу понять, почему в случае отсутствия значения "произвольное поле", которое может задаваться странице, он не подхватывает по умолчанию sidebar-second.php? Что надо изменить, чтобы подхватывал и выводил этот сайдбар, если не подключен уникальный, который задан через значение произвольного поля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `else` срабатывает на `is_single()`. То есть второй сайдбар будет выводиться только тогда, когда это условие не выполняется.

Надо примерно так:

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) {
    $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebar", true); // левый сайдбар
    if ($sidebar)
        get_sidebar($sidebar);
    else
        get_sidebar('second');
}
    else
        get_sidebar('second');
// is_single() ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись. Я скопировал код, теперь выводится сайдбар только на страницах, а в других местах нет.. Вообще конструкция is_single отвечает за вывод определённого кода на странице с записью и мне кажется дело не в ней совершенно. Потому что в файле single.php я вписал такой код `<?php $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebarg", true);
get_sidebar($sidebar); // главный сайдбар
?>` без is_single и прочего. И этот сайтбар выводится везде по умолчанию, а если задать через "произвольное поле" sidebarg за значением, то выведет нужный сайдбар.

Comment: Может в конструкцию добавить проверку значения? Если оно пустое, то выводить такой то сайдбар.. if ($sidebar != "") ... как то так :-) Я примерно написал, так как не программист :-)

Comment: `if ($sidebar)` как раз и проверяет, что значение непустое.

Comment: Вы же не сказали, что вам на всех страницах нужен вывод `second`. Поправил код в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Так работает :-) И я не указал, потому что не понимаю по какому принципу выбирается сайдбар. Вот у главного (правого) выводится главный, а у левого (о котором разговор) не выводилось ничего, типа нет умолчания. А как он задаётся не могу знать, потому то и надо, видимо, указывать конкретный в коде.

Comment: ну, если помогло, то можно отметить ответ, как принятый